# How to set the ADF V1 pipeline to run every Tuesday

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using ADF V1 in Azure.

I want my pipeline to run every Tuesday at 10:00AM. **I know how to set the time but how to set particular day of the week in dataset and pipeline?**.

I want my pipeline to run every Tuesday 10:00 AM.

my sample data set

```
{
  "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/internalschemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.table.json",
  "name": "SQL-My-Table-DS",
  "properties": {
    "structure": [
      {
        "name": "ServiceName",
        "type": "String"
      }
    ],
    "published": false,
    "type": "SqlServerTable",
    "linkedServiceName": "MyLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
      "tableName": "[common].[MyTable_Staging]"
    },
    "availability": {
      "frequency": "Week",
      "interval": 1,
      "offset": "00:00:10"
    },
    "external": false,
    "policy": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-create-datasets#offsetstyle-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using data factory version 1, you can achieve this by setting the availability with frequency month, interval 1, and set the offset with the number of the day you want the pipeline to run.

For example if you want it to run the 9th of each month as you said, you will have something like this:

```html
 "availability": {
"frequency": "Month",
"interval": 1,
"offset": "9.00:00:00", 
"style": "StartOfInterval"
}
```

**Editing the answer for week also**, below code snippet will make pipeline to run every Tuesday.

```
"availability": {
"frequency": "Week",
"interval": 1,
"offset": "2.00:00:00", 
"style": "StartOfInterval"
}
```